# How can I generate as many parameters as is the arity of a function?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have the following function, that takes a function as a parameter.

```
template <typename F>
void test_func(F f)
{
    // typedef typename function_traits<F>::return_type T;
    typedef int T;

    std::mt19937 rng(std::time(0));
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> uint_dist10(0, std::numeric_limits<T>::max());

    f(uint_dist10(rng), uint_dist10(rng)); // Problem!
}
```

Usage would be:

```
int foo(int, int) { return 0; }
int bar(int, int, int, int) { return 0; }

int main()
{
    test_func(foo);
    // test_func(bar);
}
```

Just like `foo` and `bar`, I have several functions that return `T`, and take some amount of parameters of type `T`. I would like `test_func` to generate as many calls to my RNG as the function f takes parameters. In other words, we can assume `T` is always an integer type, and that each parameter will be the same, i.e. a function call to an RNG.

Using function_traits (such as [the ones in Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html)), I can fetch the return type of `F`, and that helps a little. Roughly, my question is

> How can I generate a needed amount of function calls so that it matches the arity of the function F?

Before C++11, I would have looked at Boost.Preprocessor, or maybe relied on template specialization. Is there a nicer way of doing it now?

Comment: Well the arity is a problem indeed. If you pass bar into it, what should the other arguments be? How should anybody except you being able to select proper values? The compiler surely cannot. A workaround is wrapping the call in a lambda or another function that has the knowledge of the remaining arguments.

Comment: You could use a variadic template instead and forward the parameter pack.

Comment: @Samuel For simplicity, we can assume each argument is a call to (say) an RNG, just as in the example. Furthermore, assume `T` will always be an integer type.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how would that work? The test_func cannot pack parameters as they are explicitly defined being (int, int) forwarding them would not yield in the correct amount of params for functions with arbitrary params.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351056/create-va-list-dynamically

Comment: How about checking the arity of the passed function, then generating a variadic template list of arguments recursively, in the caller function, once done, then applying this to the passed function via a variadic blast? - This is how I would do it. For checking arity and the type of the n'th parameter simply use the function traits library, that was with my proposal to the ISO committee.

Comment: @DieterLücking: Not really; va_lists are runtime constructs and this is compile time.

Comment: As I usually do, I'll just mention that callable objects in C++ don't necessarily have a well-defined arity.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Not even functions have well-defined arity. Variadic (template) functions for example.

Comment: Templates are not functions.

Comment: @Nawaz: They're called _function templates_, and not _template functions_ for a reason.

Comment: @Xeo: Yes. I know it is called *function templates*. Please read *"Variadic (template) functions"* as "variadic functions" and "variadic function template".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First define a meta function called `arity` to compute arity of the function (it is just a simple implementation; can be improved to compute arity of functors also. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053694/c-stdfunction-cannot-find-correct-overload).):

```
template<typename F> 
struct arity;

template<typename R, typename ...Args> 
struct arity<R (*)(Args...)>
{
    static const std::size_t value = sizeof ... (Args);
};
```

then define another meta function called `genseq` to generate a compile time sequence of integral values:

```
template<int ... N>
struct seq
{
    using type = seq<N...>;

    template<int I>
    struct push_back : seq<N..., I> {};
};

template<int N>
struct genseq : genseq<N-1>::type::template push_back<N-1> {};

template<>
struct genseq<0> : seq<> {};

template<int N>
using genseq_t = typename genseq<N>::type;  //Just a friendly alias!
```

then a function invoker as:

```
template<typename F, typename ArgEvaluator, int ...N>
void invoke(seq<N...>, F f, ArgEvaluator arg_evaluator)
{
    using arg_type = decltype(arg_evaluator());

    constexpr std::size_t arity = sizeof ... (N);

    arg_type args[] { (N, arg_evaluator()) ... }; //enforce order of evaluation

    f( args[N] ... );
}
```

And then your code would become this:

```
template <typename F>
void test_func(F f)
{
    // typedef typename function_traits<F>::return_type T;
    typedef int T;

    std::mt19937 rng(std::time(0));
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> uint_dist10(0, std::numeric_limits<T>::max());

    //f(uint_dist10(rng), uint_dist10(rng)); // Problem!

      auto arg_evaluator = [&]() mutable { return uint_dist10(rng); };
      invoke(genseq_t<arity<F>::value>(), f, arg_evaluator);
}
```

[Here is a sample demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62107b59ecfce36b).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Did you know your invocations of `arg_evaluator` have unspecified evaluation order?

Comment: @Xeo: Yes. :-). It is same as in the question.

Comment: @Xeo: Because in the question, the OP is using "random" generator. Does it really matter the order in which you're calling it?

Comment: Yes: different runs could evsluate in different orders.  Without that a fixed seed produces predicable parameters, good for reproducing the test error run.

Comment: As an aside, the above fails on overloads.  There is a solution that returns the lest number of args.  Also, the above fails on `void foo(int, double, int)`, which can also be solved to be compatible with 3 `double` or 3 `int` or the like. Odds are the OP does not care.

Comment: @Yakk: It will fail in many other ways. The question is: is it required to do that? I don't see any such requirement in the question. Anyway, the "unspecified evaluation order" problem is fixed.

Answer (score 10):

No need for complicated meta calculations.

```
template <typename Ret, typename ... T>
void test_func (Ret f (T...))
{
  std::mt19937 rng(std::time(0));
  f((std::uniform_int_distribution<T>(0, std::numeric_limits<T>::max())(rng))...);
}

int moo(int, int, int){ return 0; }

int main ()
{
  test_func(moo);
}
```

To support functors one needs a bit longer implementation, still not too complicated:

```
// separate arguments type from function/functor type
template <typename F, typename ... T> 
void test_func_impl (F f)
{
  std::mt19937 rng(std::time(0));
  f((std::uniform_int_distribution<T>(0, std::numeric_limits<T>::max())(rng))...);
}

// overload for a straight function
template <typename Ret, typename ... T>
void test_func (Ret f (T...))
{
  test_func_impl<decltype(f), T...>(f);
}

// forwarder for a functor with a normal operator()
template <typename F, typename Ret, typename... T>
void test_func_for_functor (F f, Ret (F::*)(T...))
{
  test_func_impl<F, T...>(f);
}

// forwarder for a functor with a const operator()
template <typename F, typename Ret, typename... T>
void test_func_for_functor (F f, Ret (F::*)(T...)const)
{
  test_func_impl<F, T...>(f);
}

// overload for anything that has operator()
template <typename F>
void test_func (F f)
{
  test_func_for_functor(f, &F::operator());
}
```

Comment: Good solution. But note that it requires the  function signature to change!

Comment: @Nawaz Only the template arguments are different. It rarely matters. You can always wrap it in a `template <typename F> void correct_func(F f)` if desired.

Comment: What I mean is that if the caller uses functor instead of function, this wouldn't work. Mine (in the current form) wouldn't work either. But as I said in the answer itself, it all needs a more sophisticated implementation of `arity` meta function. All else will remain same. I also provided a link to my other answer which give some idea as to how to implement `arity` to work with functors.

Comment: I see what you mean.  It's easy to provide an overload for functors too. Will update the answer soon.

Comment: Yes. But overloading for functors require *"complicated meta calculations"* which you wanted to avoid in the first place. It wouldn't be this simple anymore. :-)

Comment: Note that the number of overloads needed is quite horrible if you also need to support all kind of funciton cv/ref qualifiers.

Comment: @Morwenn I have never seen "v" member functions used in practice, only "c", so I won't bother. Wouldn't you need the same number of overloads to implement `arity` from the other solution?

Comment: Also, I am not sure, but a result of `std::bind` may have multiple overloads of `operator()` which means that `&F::operator()` may be rejected by the compiler for being ambiguous.

Comment: @n.m. That's totally right. To get around the problem, all the boilerplate is generally written in `function_traits` (which can be reused).

Comment: @Morwenn "&F::operator() may be rejected by the compiler for being ambiguous". That's exactly the right thing to do. Which `operator()` would *you* select?

Comment: @Morwenn You can wrap this method into a reusable package too.

Comment: Careful there. You fell prey to the unspecified evaluation order of arguments.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Not sure where, can you point out the line?

Comment: @n.m. I don't know, but I wouldn't have expected multiple overloads of `operator()` by a result of `std::bind` before running into the problem.