# No clang warning or error, if C++11 lambda returns wrong type

Tags: c++, c++11, types, lambda, clang

it looks like my clang compiler (3.3) doesn't generate any errors, if the lambda's return type doesn't match:

```
#include <functional>
typedef std::function<void()> voidFunc;

void foo(voidFunc func) 
{
    func();
}

int main() 
{
    int i = 42;
    foo([i]()
    {
        return i;
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code doesn't show any errors:

```
clang++ -c -Xclang -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-missing-prototypes -o foo.o foo.cpp
```

How can I generate type errors for problems like this?

**EDIT:**

This generates a type error:

```
#include <functional>

struct A {};
struct B {};

typedef std::function<A()> aFunc;

void foo(aFunc func)
{
    func();
}

int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    foo([i]() 
    {
        return B();
    });
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error:

```
foo2.cpp:16:2: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
        foo([i]() {
        ^~~
foo2.cpp:8:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from '<lambda at foo2.cpp:16:6>' to 'aFunc' (aka 'function<A ()>') for 1st argument
void foo(aFunc func)
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Check the documentation for `std::function`. No errors here is by design.

Comment: No error by design? This is strange, if you come from a Haskell background. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This is... by design?! This is strange, if you come from a human background, and/or have any common sense whatsoever.

Comment: @SebastianPhilipp if you come from a Haskell background, `std::function<b(a)>` is not `a -> b`. Don't make assumptions like that.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Why not?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit A function that returns a value can be used everywhere a function that doesn't return one would. It's return type covariance.

Comment: This would be the Haskell equivalent: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/529745317af9d091

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/9339829/420683

Comment: dyp: yep it's a dublicate, but I didn't found the other Q by searching  for this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::function` is a polymorphic container for callable objects that support a particular call signature†.

The lambda in the example can be called the same way a `void()` function is called; ignoring return values was never a type error in C++ (whether that is a good or a bad idea is a different question).

Therefore, `std::function<void()>` allows such an object. The first program shown is perfectly valid.

The lambda in the second program, however, cannot be called anywhere a `A()` function could:

```
void f(A const&);
f(the_lambda()); // nope!
```

So the second program is not valid, and the compiler correctly reports that.

If you want a type error in a situation like this, you need to do your own type checking. In this case, you can simply `static_assert` that `std::result_of<T()>::type` is the same as `void`. However, in general, this is *impossible* because in C++ all callables (except degenerate ones like `void()`) have more than one possible call signature, thanks to features like implicit conversions.

---

† I might have to explain what I mean by "call signature" here. I mean the types used in an actual call, or potentially a call + assignment of return value, not the types that are explictly present in the declared signature. Consider the following code.

```
long f(double);

double d;
int i;

long a = f(d);  // call signature is long(double)
                // called with double, returning into a long
short b = f(i); // call signature is short(int)
                // called with int, returning into a short
```

Comment: The words "type erasure" might be worth mentioning.

Comment: *"ignoring return values was never a type error in C++"* `INVOKE` requires implicit convertibility to the return type. No type can be *implicitly* converted to `void`, since implicit conversion is defined as `T t=e;` and `T` is `void` here. (See also: [`is_convertible`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e45cdcb7aefdcf8c)) There *has been* an exception for `void` return types before [LWG 870](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-defects.html#870), but this exception has been removed. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9343400/420683

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is a minor symptom of undefined behavior, or an error in the standard, or errors in compilers.

The general rule is that a `std::function<A(B...)>` does not enforce that the signature of passed function objects or pointers exactly match `A(B...)`, but rather that they be compatible.

The standard describes this in terms of calling the incoming callable object with types `B...` and the result is implicitly convertible to `A`.

Now, the issue is that nothing is implicitly convertible to `void`.  Arguably even `void` is not implicitly converted to `void`.

Some compilers take this clause, and interpret it to mean that `std::function<void(B...)>` can only be constructed from callables that return `void` when invoked with `B...` types.  Others interpret it to mean that `std::function<void(B...)>` can be constructed from any callable that can be invoked with `B...` types.

I'm unsure what the standard says the language should do if the object you construct the `std::function` from violates the requirements dictated in the standard.

Now, to fix your problem, you can write this:

```
template<typename T, typename Sig>
struct invoke_return_value_matches;
template<typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
struct invoke_return_value_matches<T, R(Args...)>:
  std::is_same< typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type, R >::type
{};
```

which is a trait that checks if the return value of invoking `T` with `Args...` matches `R` exactly.

If we want to create a quick wrapper for `std::function` that enforces exact match on return values:

```
template<typename Sig>
struct exact_function {
  std::function<Sig> f;
  template<typename...Args>
  typename std::result_of< (Sig*)(Args...) >::type
  operator()(Args&&...args) const {
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  operator std::function<Sig>() const { return f; }
  operator std::function<Sig>() && { return std::move(f); }
  exact_function() = default;
  exact_function(exact_function const&)=default;
  exact_function(exact_function&&)=default;
  exact_function& operator=(exact_function const&)=default;
  exact_function& operator=(exact_function&&)=default;
  template<
    typename T,
    typename=typename std::enable_if<invoke_return_type_matches<T,Sig>::value>::type
  >
  exact_function( T&& t ):f(std::forward<T>(t)) {}
  exact_function( Sig* raw_func ):f(raw_func) {}
};
```

should be pretty close to what you want.  I'm mainly just forwarding crap to the `std::function` internally, except I'm intercepting generic construct and applying your test.

Comment: *"I'm unsure what the standard says the language should do if the object you construct the std::function from violates the requirements dictated in the standard."* [Howard Hinnant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9343400/420683) says it's UB, and I'd agree, considering [res.on.required]

Comment: Why don't you use a trailing-return-type for `operator()`?

Comment: @dyp In C++1y, I would just use `auto`.  Some compilers with won't support `this` scoped variables in trailing return type.  As I was able to do it without trailing or `this` capture, I did it?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I remember some strange problems with member variables (and/or `this`) in trailing return types.

Comment: @dyp did inspire me to improve the return type

Comment: @dyp `result_of<int(double)>` is an error.  `result_of< int(*)(double)(float) >::type` is `int`.

Comment: ... I always get confused by `result_of` :(

Answer (score 1):

Clang 3.4 on Mac OS rejects your code:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
    foo([i]() {
    ^~~
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion
    from '<lambda at t.cpp:10:9>' to 'voidFunc'
      (aka 'function<void ()>') for 1st argument
void foo(voidFunc func) {
     ^
```

`clang++ --version` on my system says:

```
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
```

Comment: This is, what I expected. Is this specific for Mac OS or a feature in Clang 3.4?

Comment: That sounds broken. Clang 3.4 on my (non-OSX) box works fine.

Comment: So I guess they fixed the bug after Apple branded their version.

Comment: I'd love to have this broken clang version

Comment: @SebastianPhilipp: I will sell you my 2011 Macbook Air with the holy Clang installed for $800 shipped worldwide.

Comment: @SebastianPhilipp that said, why is this what you expected? Why would one expect a behaviour contrary to the one that this was designed for?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes because I'd expect that return type covariance is limited to object orientation and that I get a type error here. "This is documented" doesn't improve the situation for me here.

Comment: @SebastianPhilipp: C++ is not sufficiently primitive to only handle that in this specific case. The intended behaviour is that `std::function<void()>` simply drops the return value in this situation.

Comment: @SebastianPhilipp The standard contains stranger things. Look at `std::bind` for example.

Comment: @Puppy really?  Are you **sure**?

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of `std::function<R(Args...)>` requires an argument `f` that is `Callable` with argument types `Args...` and return type `R`; that is, one for which *`INVOKE`*`(f,  t1, t2, ..., tN)` implicitly converted to `R` is valid.

Note that conversion is allowed on function *arguments*, so there's no good reason to disallow it on the return type as well.

If you want to only accept arguments that have a specific return type, you can use `result_of` and `is_same`:

```
template<typename F>
auto foo(F&& func) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<
    typename std::result_of<F()>::type, void>::value>::type
{
    std::forward<F>(func)();
}
```