# Incompatible function types allowed in libstdc++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm compiling a simple (and possibly erroneous) C++ file:

```
// file test_function.cpp
#include <functional>

void foo()
{
    void* (*func)() = nullptr;
    std::function<void()> func_(func);
}
```

I think the type of func_ should be `std::function<void*()>`. As expected, clang++ with libc++ gives an error:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 -c -stdlib=libc++ test_function.cpp
test_function.cpp:6:27: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::function<void ()>'
    std::function<void()> func_(func);
                          ^     ~~~~
```

However, g++ and clang++ with libstdc++ gives no errors:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 -c -stdlib=libstdc++ test_function.cpp
$ g++ -std=c++14 -c test_function.cpp
```

Is the situation normal? Are there descriptions about function type conversion in C++ standards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you think that the type of `func` should be `std::function<void*()>`. After all, you defined `func_` otherwise, as `std::function<void()>`. The definition of `func_` determines its type.

The error you get is related to the question whether you can ignore the return type of `func`, the raw function pointer (Your choice of names is rather confusing TBH). This should be possible.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/a/9343400/3786245, the _proper_ and _safe_ usage should be `std::function<void*()>`. Am I correct?

Comment: It's the proper usage if you need the return value. If you don't, void() is fine.