# What is "Expression SFINAE"?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++11, sfinae

At http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx, the VC++ team officially declare that they have not yet implemented the C++11 core feature "Expression SFINAE". However, The following code examples copied from http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2634.html are accepted by the VC++ compiler.

example 1:

```
template <int I> struct A {};

char xxx(int);
char xxx(float);

template <class T> A<sizeof(xxx((T)0))> f(T){}

int main()
{
    f(1);
}
```

example 2:

```
struct X {};
struct Y 
{
    Y(X){}
};

template <class T> auto f(T t1, T t2) -> decltype(t1 + t2); // #1
X f(Y, Y);  // #2

X x1, x2;
X x3 = f(x1, x2);  // deduction fails on #1 (cannot add X+X), calls #2
```

**My question is: What is "Expression SFINAE"?**

Comment: Why do not look in the obvious: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error

Comment: @SChepurin: That explains normal SFINAE, not Expression SFINAE. It's a good point, though. Does OP know about SFINAE in general?

Comment: @Xeo, Yes, I know SFINAE in general. Many thanks to you for your illustrative explanation.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Expression SFINAE is explained quite well in the paper you linked, I think. It's [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) on expressions. If the expression inside `decltype` isn't valid, well, kick the function from the VIP lounge of overloads. You can find the normative wording at the end of this answer.

A note on VC++: They didn't implement it *completely*. On simple expressions, it might work, but on others, it won't. See a discussion in the comments [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6194623/500104) for examples that fail. To make it simple, this won't work:

```
#include <iostream>

// catch-all case
void test(...)
{
  std::cout << "Couldn't call\n";
}

// catch when C is a reference-to-class type and F is a member function pointer
template<class C, class F>
auto test(C c, F f) -> decltype((c.*f)(), void()) // 'C' is reference type
{
  std::cout << "Could call on reference\n";
}

// catch when C is a pointer-to-class type and F is a member function pointer
template<class C, class F>
auto test(C c, F f) -> decltype((c->*f)(), void()) // 'C' is pointer type
{
  std::cout << "Could call on pointer\n";
}

struct X{
  void f(){}
};

int main(){
  X x;
  test(x, &X::f);
  test(&x, &X::f);
  test(42, 1337);
}
```

With Clang, this outputs the expected:

> Could call with reference
> Could call with pointer
> Couldn't call

With MSVC, I get... well, a compiler error:

```
1>src\main.cpp(20): error C2995: ''unknown-type' test(C,F)' : function template has already been defined
1>          src\main.cpp(11) : see declaration of 'test'
```

It also seems that GCC 4.7.1 isn't quite up to the task:

```
source.cpp: In substitution of 'template decltype ((c.*f(), void())) test(C, F) [with C = X*; F = void (X::*)()]':
source.cpp:29:17:   required from here
source.cpp:11:6: error: cannot apply member pointer 'f' to 'c', which is of non-class type 'X*'
source.cpp: In substitution of 'template decltype ((c.*f(), void())) test(C, F) [with C = int; F = int]':
source.cpp:30:16:   required from here
source.cpp:11:6: error: 'f' cannot be used as a member pointer, since it is of type 'int'
```

A common use of Expression SFINAE is when defining traits, like a trait to check if a class sports a certain member function:

```
struct has_member_begin_test{
  template<class U>
  static auto test(U* p) -> decltype(p->begin(), std::true_type());
  template<class>
  static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;
};

template<class T>
struct has_member_begin
  : decltype(has_member_begin_test::test<T>(0)) {};
```

[Live example.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/45043173e3b62ee33deaeec3e609516a) (Which, surprisingly, works again on GCC 4.7.1.)

See also [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9154394/500104), which uses the same technique in another environment (aka without traits).

---

Normative wording:

`§14.8.2 [temp.deduct]`

> p6 **At certain points in the template argument deduction process it is necessary to take a function type that makes use of template parameters and replace those template parameters with the corresponding template arguments.** This is done at the beginning of template argument deduction when any explicitly specified template arguments are substituted into the function type, and **again at the end of template argument deduction when any template arguments that were deduced or obtained from default arguments are substituted**.
>
> p7 **The substitution occurs in all types and expressions** that are used in the function type and in template parameter declarations. **The expressions include not only constant expressions** such as those that appear in array bounds or as nontype template arguments **but also general expressions** (i.e., non-constant expressions) **inside** `sizeof`, **`decltype`**, and other contexts that allow non-constant expressions.
>
> p8 If a substitution results in an invalid type or expression, type deduction fails. An invalid type or expression is one that would be ill-formed if written using the substituted arguments. [...]

Comment: I was wondering why suddenly there appeared to be links to liveworkspace instead of ideone, when I noticed that liveworkspace is using gcc 4.7.2. Ah! Finally!

Comment: The live example link is broken :(

Comment: Compiles fine in MSVC 2017.