# Seemingly ambiguous template function overloads

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, overload-resolution

The original problem I tried to solve when stumbled upon this was to select `parse_impl` version:

- if the parser (of type `U`) provides a field named `"skp"`, use that field;
- if not, use a default value.

I came up with the following code:

```
// This variant compiles for parsers requiring a skipper:
template <typename I, typename U, typename A,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<
              not std::is_same<
                  typename std::remove_reference<U>::type::skipper_type,
                  qi::unused_type
              >::value
          >::type,
          typename = void > // avoid redefinition (1 more overload not shown)
bool parse_impl(I & start, I end, U && parser, A & attr)
{
    // qi::space by default:
    return qi::phrase_parse(start, end, parser, qi::space, attr);
}

// This variant compiles for parsers providing skipper via 'skp' member:
template <typename I, typename U, typename A,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<
              not std::is_same<
                  typename std::remove_reference<U>::type::skipper_type,
                  qi::unused_type
              >::value
              && (sizeof(U::skp) != 0)
          >::type,
          typename = void, typename = void > // avoid redefinition
bool parse_impl(I & start, I end, U && parser, A & attr)
{
    // parser.skp is available:
    return qi::phrase_parse(start, end, parser, parser.skp, attr);
}
```

The call site look like this:

```
pr.is_ok = parse_impl(pr.position, input.cend(), parser, pr.attr);
```

and this is called both for types having `skp` and ones that haven't.

And it compiles (on gcc4.7), but I don't understand why: when `skp` is present, expressions in both `enable_if`s should evaluate to true (`skipper_type` is obviously not equal to `unused_type` then), and the call should be ambiguous. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: [A reduced test case](http://liveworkspace.org/code/5a6093ff1c940b48071231ec1d1d12bf) atleast is ambiguous and I can't see if I did anything different there. I can only guess that your third overload, the one with `skp`, never actually gets called for some reason, if this does indeed compile for you. Maybe put some test print statements in them? Lastly, I recommend reading [this blog post](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/06/01/almost-static-if.html) aswell as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12654067/500104) question and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9154394/500104) answer. :)

Comment: @Xeo: I've finally nailed it. There is difference, actually: `sizeof(NoRef<T>::skp)` in your code vs `(sizeof(U::skp) != 0)` in mine. `NoRef` has finally brought the ambiguity in! *HUGE* thanks for help  and the links!

Comment: Ah, so your problem was that when you pass an lvalue (and `U` is deduced as a reference), you get your SFINAE going. :) And indeed, [that's the problem](http://liveworkspace.org/code/f35132f82751e262fd6a64515e11bebd).

Comment: Since there hasn't been any action from your side, should I just post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, as concluded in the comments, that when using just `U::skp`, it might be that `U` is deduced as a reference type (i.e., when passing an lvalue parser). When this happens, you get SFINAE going, as a reference type obviously has no nested *anything*.

The fix is to remove the reference from `U` with `std::remove_reference` so that you have `(sizeof(std::remove_reference<T>::type::skp) != 0)`. Note that `typename` is not needed here, since `::skp` indicates that `type` has to be a typename.