# templates, decltype and non-classtypes

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype

I have a function definition like so

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto print(T t) -> decltype(t.print()) {
    return t.print();
}
```

The idea is that the argument must be of type `T` and must have the `print` function. This `print` function could return anything, explaining the need of `decltype`. So for example you can do:

```
struct Foo
{
    int print()
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

struct Bar
{
    std::string print()
    {
        return "The answer...";
    }
};

...

std::cout << print(Foo()) << std::endl;    
std::cout << print(Bar()) << std::endl;
/* outputs: 
42
The answer...
*/
```

I read that templates cannot do runtime instantiation and that you can have the classes derive from a base class, then determine their types to see what template argument to use. However, how would I do this for a `non-class` type? The idea is to be able to have:

```
template <typename T>
T print(T t) {
    return t;
}
```

as well, but this gives me ambiguous overload errors. Qualifying doesn't work, ie `print<Foo>`. And the other got'cha is, what if I had a functor like:

```
struct Foo
{
  virtual int print();
  operator int() const
  {
    return 42;
  }
};
```

How does it decide now?

So my question is, is it possible to resolve all these ambiguities with templates, or do I have to write a bunch of redundant code?

**Tests**

I incrementally added tests, copy/pasting each edit'ed solution from below. Here are the results:

With the following classes:

```
struct Foo
{
    int print()
    {
        return 42;
    }

    operator int() const
    {
        return 32;
    }
};

struct Bar
{
    std::string print()
    {
        return "The answer...";
    }

    operator int() const
    {
        return (int)Foo();
    }
};

struct Baz
{
    operator std::string() const
    {
        return std::string("The answer...");
    }
};
```

And the following test output:

```
std::cout << print(Foo()) << std::endl;    
std::cout << print(Bar()) << std::endl;
std::cout << print(42) << std::endl;
std::cout << print((int)Foo()) << std::endl;
std::cout << print("The answer...") << std::endl;
std::cout << print(std::string("The answer...")) << std::endl;
std::cout << print((int)Bar()) << std::endl;
std::cout << print((std::string)Baz()) << std::endl;
```

Both correctly output:

```
42
The answer...
42
32
The answer...
The answer...
32
The answer...
```

Comment: This is a case for [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error). In a nutshell: You define your first implementation *only* for those types which have `T::print()`, and the second for all other cases. Another option is to overload your function manually with all types which you want to support but don't have a print function, like: `int print(int);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could adopt the following approach, which invokes a `print()` member function on the input if such a member function exists, otherwise it will return the input itself:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename T, typename = void>
    struct print_helper
    {
        static T print(T t) {
            return t;
        }
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct print_helper<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().print(), (void)0)>
    {
        static auto print(T t) -> decltype(t.print()) {
            return t.print();
        }
    };
}

template<typename T>
auto print(T t) -> decltype(detail::print_helper<T>::print(t))
{
    return detail::print_helper<T>::print(t);
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/EDa20G).

Comment: I think you have your conditions reversed.

Comment: @Xeo: Yes, and I am going to edit anyway - I don't like this version ;)

Comment: Now that I have seen this construct a couple of times and still don't know how it's called, how / why it works and how to write it by myself: Can you point me to some nice documentation or tell me if it has a name? (It isn't a type trait, but it *is* SINFAE, isn't it?)

Comment: @leemes: Yes, it is called *expression SFINAE*. You can find more info about it for instance in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654067/what-is-expression-sfinae)

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution using manual **overloading** for each type which you want to print *directly*:

Define your first implementation which calls `T::print()`. Use overloading to specify alternative implementations for all types which don't have this function. I don't recommend this solution, but it's very easy to understand.

```
template<typename T>
auto print(T t) -> decltype(t.print()) {
    return t.print();
}

int print(int t) {
    return t;
}
std::string print(std::string t) {
    return t;
}
// ... and so on, for each type you want to support ...
```

---

More advanced solution using **SFINAE** which uses `T::print()` automatically if and only if it's there:

First, define a trait which can decide if your type has a function `print()`. Basically, this trait inherits from either `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`, depending on the decision being made in some helper class (`_test_print`). Then, use this type trait in an [`enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) compile-time decision which defines *only one* of the two cases and hides the other one (so this is *not* overloading).

```
// Type trait "has_print" which checks if T::print() is available:
struct _test_print {
    template<class T> static auto test(T* p) -> decltype(p->print(), std::true_type());
    template<class>   static auto test(...)  -> std::false_type;
};
template<class T> struct has_print : public decltype(_test_print::test<T>(0)) {};


// Definition of print(T) if T has T::print():
template<typename T>
auto print(T t) -> typename std::enable_if<has_print<T>::value, decltype(t.print())>::type {
    return t.print();
}

// Definition of print(T) if T doesn't have T::print():
template<typename T>
auto print(T t) -> typename std::enable_if<!has_print<T>::value, T>::type {
    return t;
}
```

Have a look at the [**live demo**](http://ideone.com/WMhh7k).

Comment: Going to have to go with this. This works with non-fundamental types like `string`s and `const char`.

Comment: Sorry that I mixed `<class T>` and `<typename T>`; this is because I copy-pasted the checking type trait from one of my projects. It's the same, if you didn't know yet. ;)

Comment: @remyabel: (I did update my answer so that it works for non-fundamental types as well. Admittedly, the first version was a bad one)

Comment: I added some test output, so I haven't chosen an answer yet. I'm curious as to what subtle differences there are, and the outputs show.

Comment: @remyabel Andy's and my answer are essentially the same, they just use different language constructs. Mine uses SFINAE, his uses template specialization. They lead exactly to the same result. They just look and work different internally ;)

Comment: @remyabel: I just tried your test case with the last version of my answer and it gives the same result as leemes's solution (see [here](http://ideone.com/coQY6O))

Comment: Personally (and this is only my personal taste), I like my solution more because it first defines a reusable type trait. But maybe this is because I have difficulties understanding Andy's solution. I've seen such a solution multiple times, but I understand type traits easier.

Comment: I will accept an answer when I can give a bounty since you both gave me quick and accurate answers.

Comment: @remyabel: At least for what concerns my answer, I don't think it deserves any bounty ;) And I do not mind if you will accept leemes's answer, because apart from personal taste for one or the other idiom, it is objectively not worse than mine.