# How do enable a function only if the class from which it is derived has a certain function?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a function, let's call it `Base`, which takes `Derived` as a template parameter and is also the base class of `Derived`, which defines a method *if* a certain method in `Derived` is defined.

Here is how I've attempted to implement this (derived from response to this question: [How to let a base method be defined only if the derived class does not define a method of the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070101/how-to-let-a-base-method-be-defined-only-if-the-derived-class-does-not-define-a/25070207?noredirect=1#comment39004445_25070207))

```
#include <utility>

struct GetValueImpl
{
    template <typename T>
    static auto test(int) -> decltype(
        std::declval<T&>().GetValue(0),
        std::true_type{});
    template <typename...>
    static std::false_type test(...);
};
template <typename T>
struct GetValueDefined : public decltype(GetValueImpl::test<T>(0)) {};

template <typename Derived, int X>
class Base
{
    public:

    // I want to define this function only if GetValue is defined in Derived
    template <typename... Args>
    auto Test(const Args&...) -> typename std::enable_if<GetValueDefined<Derived>::value>::type
    {
    }
};

template <std::int32_t val>
class DerivedExample : public Base<DerivedExample<val>, 1>
{
    public:
    template <typename T>
    int GetValue() {return 0;}
};

int main() {
    DerivedExample<1> d;
    d.Test(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

This produces the following compiler error:

```
prog.cpp:21:10: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
     auto Test(const Args&...) -> typename std::enable_if<GetValueDefined<Derived>::value>::type
          ^
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:36:7: error: ‘class DerivedExample<1>’ has no member named ‘Test’
     d.Test(1, 2);
       ^
```

[working example here](http://ideone.com/lvDcSB).

Clearly my `std::enable_if` check is failing. But why?

Comment: Having a base class depend on the behavior of a child class is a design smell, IMO.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't disagree :) This is more of an exercise, I'm actually trying to do the inverse (see the linked question) but in trying to diagnose a related problem I tried switching the logic to create the function *if* the derived function exists, and I couldn't do it, so I posted this.

Comment: You check for validity of `t.GetValue(0)` (with param) which is not provided by `DerivedExample`...

Answer (score 1):

The SFINAE mechanism has to rely on names from the current template. Use a default argument for `Derived` so a (un)sucessful substitution can occur:

```
template <typename D = Derived, typename... Args>
auto Test(const Args&...) -> typename std::enable_if<GetValueDefined<D>::value>::type
{
}
```

Comment: @Arman: After changing some code to have `GetValueDefined<DerivedExample>::value == true`, it compiles (http://ideone.com/GyfTTd)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will be of any help but you should look into the pre-proccessor commands like

```
#ifndef // if the class is not defined
#define // defines class
#endif  // ends if statement
```

For Example

```
#include "whatever.h" 
#ifndef CLASS_H 
#define CLASS_H
class base
{
 public:
 base(){}
 ~base(){}
 private:
 };
 #endif
```