# Is the "lazy man's enable_if" legal C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, language-lawyer, sfinae

I frequently use a technique I call the "lazy man's `enable_if`," where I use `decltype` and the comma operator to enable a function based on some template input. Here is a small example:

```
template <typename F>
auto foo(F&& f) -> decltype(f(0), void())
{
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
}

template <typename F>
auto foo(F&& f) -> decltype(f(0, 1), void())
{
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}
```

With `--std=c++11`, g++ 4.7+ and Clang 3.5+ happily compile that bit of code (and it works as I would expect). However, when using MSVC 14 CTP5, I get this error complaining of `foo` already being defined:

> Error error C2995: 'unknown-type foo(F &&)': function template has
>   already been defined  c++-scratch main.cpp    15

So my question is: Is the "lazy man's `enable_if`" legal C++ or is this an MSVC bug?

Comment: It's certainly legal. MSVC doesn't have the best track record when it comes to standard conformance.

Comment: MSVC isn't C++11 compliant yet. For example, constexpr doesn't work yet.

Comment: Adding an unused parameter `, typename = void` to the second `foo` can make MSVC2015 Preview compile.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[[temp.over.link]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link#6) specifies when two function template declarations are overloads. That is done by defining equivalency of two function templates as follows:

> Two function templates are *equivalent* if they [..] have return types [..] that are equivalent using the rules
>   described above to compare expressions involving template parameters.

The "rules described above" are

> Two expressions involving template parameters are considered
>   *equivalent* if two function definitions containing the expressions would satisfy the one definition rule (3.2) [..]

The ODR relevant for this part states in [[basic.def.odr]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#6) that

> Given such an entity named `D` defined in more than one translation
>   unit, then
>
> - **each definition of `D` shall consist of the same sequence of tokens**;

Clearly, as the return types (which are the trailing return types as per [[dcl.fct]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#2)) do not consist of the same tokens, two function definitions containing those expressions would violate the ODR.
Hence the declarations of `foo` declare non-equivalent function templates and overload the name.

The error you see is issued due to the lack of support from VC++ for expression SFINAE - presumably the trailing-return-types are not inspected for equivalency.

---

#### Workaround

You can make the function templates non-equivalent in another way - Change the template parameter list. If you rewrite the second definition like so:

```
template <typename F, int=0>
auto foo(F&& f) -> decltype(f(0, 1), void())
{
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}
```

Then VC++ [compiles it fine](http://rextester.com/CED85004).
I shortened the quote in [temp.over.link]/6, which covers this:

> Two function templates are *equivalent* if they are declared in the same
>   scope, have the same name, **have identical template parameter lists** [..]

In fact, to be able to easily introduce new overloads, you can use a little helper:

```
template <int I>
using overload = std::integral_constant<int, I>*;
```

Usage is e.g.

```
// Remember to separate > and = with whitespace
template <typename... F, overload<0> = nullptr>
auto foo(F&&... f) -> decltype(f(0, 1)..., void())

template <typename... F, overload<1> = nullptr>
auto foo(F&&... f) -> decltype(f(0, 1, 2)..., void())
```

[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/AGOD13940).

Comment: `template<size_t> struct overload{enum type{}}` then `template<typename F, overload<0>::type...>` has no limit on the number of overloads, but clang explodes when fed it sadly.

Comment: @Yakk I used a pointer type instead (because I can currently not check the conversions allowed for converted constant expressions), but good idea, nested types are obviously unique. Kinda missed that :) As you can see I chose to use a default argument instead of a pack, because of problems in combination with other packs.

Comment: @Yakk Further simplified after I understood the difference in parsing between template argument and template parameter lists.

Comment: That is nice!  Even using the `=0` in a somewhat non-evil way.  Still, I hope that concepts lite will make this kind of hack not required, I should check if they covered the problem.

Comment: @Yakk Turned out the =0 is incorrect since null pointer conversions in *converted constant expressions* can only convert from `nullptr_t`. Fixed.

Answer (score 34):

This is a feature called ["Expression SFINAE."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654067/what-is-expression-sfinae)  It is not yet fully supported by Visual C++ (see ["C++11/14/17 Features In VS 2015 Preview"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx) for the latest conformance update as of the time of this answer).

Comment: Thanks! At least it's workaroundable. Is there any word on if this will get fixed for the big release?