# Template non-type arguments for reference type and odr-used

Tags: c++, boost, language-lawyer

Is the variable `v` in the sample code below *odr-used*?

```
extern void* v;

template<void*&>
void f() {}

int main()
{
    f<v>();
}
```

I found this pattern in Boost ML.

cf. http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2011/04/180082.php

It says that the `boost::enabler` is never defined, but **clang** rejects it as a linkage error if `-g` option is provided.

cf. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nF45k7un3rFb175z

The sample code above is reduced version of the Boost ML's code and **clang** rejects it too.

cf. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ZwxaygXgUhbi1Cbr

I think (but I am not sure) that template non-type arguments for reference type are *odr-used* even if they are not referred in their template body so the Boost ML's pattern is ill-formed.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[basic.def.odr]/3:

> A variable `x` whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression
>   `ex` is *odr-used* by `ex` **unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion
>   (4.1) to `x` yields a constant expression (5.19)** [..]

Unfortunately, applying the l-t-r conversion to `v` at this point would not yield a constant expression - [expr.const]/2:

> A *conditional-expression* `e` is a core constant expression unless
>   the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine
>   (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions:  [..]
>
> — an
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to
>
> - a non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type **that refers to a non-volatile const object with   a preceding
>     initialization**, initialized with a constant expression [..], or
> - a non-volatile glvalue **that refers to a non-volatile object defined with `constexpr`**, or that refers
>            to a non-mutable sub-object of such an object, or
> - a non-volatile glvalue of literal type **that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`**;

However, though the implementation suggested by Matt isn't correct, the idea certainly is. A simple way of using this approach is demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28204207/3647361), using a helper template. In your case, try

```
template <bool cond, int id=0>
using distinct_enable_if =
    typename std::enable_if<cond, std::integral_constant<int,id>*>::type;

class test
{
public:
  template< class... T,
            distinct_enable_if<sizeof...(T) == 10> = nullptr> 
  test( T&&... ) {}

  template< class T,
            distinct_enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>{}> = nullptr>
  operator T() const { return T{}; }

  /* Note the additional template argument:
     It ensures that the template parameter lists are not identical, 
     and the ODR isn't violated */
  template< class T,
            distinct_enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>{}, 1> = nullptr>
  operator T() const { return T{}; }
};
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95a352c06b1c1442).

Comment: Thanks.  I am sure that my understanding is correct.  But I am not sure how to use a helper template.  Where should I use a helper template for the case of the `boost::enable_if_c`?

Comment: @MitsuruKariya Extended the answer.

Answer (score 7):

I believe `v` is *odr-used*. `f<v>` is a *template-id* (**14.2**) whose *template-argument* is an *id-expression* (**5.1.1**) - a form of expression. It's clearly not an unevaluated operand (it doesn't appear as an operand of `typeid`, `sizeof`, `noexcept` or `decltype`), so it's *potentially evaluated* per **3.2/2**:

> **3.2/2** An expression is *potentially evaluated* unless it is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5) or a subexpression thereof...

At which point, we have

> **3.2/3** A variable `x` whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression `ex` is *odr-used* unless [a condition that doesn't appear to apply here as no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied].

Comment: Thanks.  I am sure that my understanding is correct.