# C++ traits classes to detect member function: compiler error in MSVC 2015 RC

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, visual-studio-2015, sfinae

The following traits classes are used to check whether a generic vector has `operator[](int)` or `operator()(int)`:

```
template<typename ...> using void_t = void;

template< typename, typename = void>
struct has_bracket_operator : public std::false_type {};

template<typename V>
struct has_bracket_operator<V, void_t<decltype(std::declval<V>()[int{}])> >
    : public std::true_type{};

template<typename, typename = void>
struct has_parenthesis_operator : public std::false_type {};

template<typename V>
struct has_parenthesis_operator<V, void_t<decltype(std::declval<V>()(int{}))> >
    : public std::true_type{};
```

It seems to [compile well in gcc 5.1.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b2b057ff1fad0b2)

---

On the other hand, in the latest MSVC download (*Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 RC Version 14.0.22823.1 D14REL*), I get a compiler error for the `has_parenthesis_operator` template which reads:

> ```
> error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
> ```

Moreover, the following version I find preferable do both not compile at all (note that `operator[](int{})` is used instead of `[int{}]`, and similar for the parenthesis):

```
template<typename V>
struct has_bracket_operator<V, void_t<decltype(std::declval<V>().operator[](int{}))> >
    : public std::true_type{};

//...

template<typename V>
struct has_parenthesis_operator<V, void_t<decltype(std::declval<V>().operator()(int{}))> >
    : public std::true_type{};
```

The error message here is

> ```
> error C2228: left of '.[]' must have class/struct/union
> note: type is 'add_rvalue_reference<V>::type'
> error C2228: left of '.()' must have class/struct/union
> note: type is 'add_rvalue_reference<V>::type'
> ```

**Questions:**

- Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong (which gcc accepts somehow)?
- Is there a workaround by which I can use the above techniques (particularly `void_t`)
- If a workaround is not possible, how to set up an alternate SFINAE check in MSVC (I tried much of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature) but didn't really succeed -- at least in *in MSVC*)?

Comment: Those checks depend on expression SFINAE, which MSVC doesn't support.

Comment: I swear there are some intrinsic, like `__has_member`, I have used.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @T.C., the above approach via `void_t<decltype(...)>` requires [expression SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12654277/2412846), which is not available in the present version of MSVC 2015.

Here is the current status on the implementation of expression SFINAE, taken from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/04/29/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rc.aspx):

> Q. When will you implement Expression SFINAE?
>
> A. We're planning to start implementing Expression SFINAE in the
>   compiler immediately after 2015 RTM, and we're planning to deliver it
>   in an Update to 2015, supported for production use.  (But not
>   necessarily 2015 Update 1.  It might take longer.)
>
> To be extra clear, this applies to the compiler only, not the
>   libraries.  The C++11 Standard Library mandated the use of Expression
>   SFINAE in a small number of places, which we've actually already
>   implemented.  (The places are is_assignable and allocator_traits,
>   which the compiler has taken special care to support.)  The C++14
>   Standard Library added two more places where Expression SFINAE must be
>   used: std::function construction/assignment and result_of.  I'll
>   modify the STL when the compiler is ready, but I'm not planning to
>   ship those library changes in an Update.
>   ...

---

Moreover, here is an *a bit* more old-fashioned workaround for the above traits using traditional SFINAE (inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16824239/2412846)):

```
template<typename C, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct has_parenthesis_operator<C, Ret(Args...)>
{
private:
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr auto check(T*) 
        -> typename std::is_same<std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().operator()(std::declval<Args>()...))>, Ret>::type;

    template<typename> static constexpr std::false_type check(...);

    typedef decltype(check<C>(0)) type;

public:
    static constexpr bool value = type::value;
};
```

which can be used for example as

```
template<typename V
       , typename = std::enable_if_t<has_bracket_operator<V, double(int)>::value>
auto get(V const& v, int i)
{
    return v[i];
}
```

This checks whether the passed vector type has a member `double operator[](int)`, and if so calls it (--otherwise one can do similar with the parenthesis operator).

---

Regardign the comment by @Yakk: I encountered the [`__if_exists` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7wy9xh3(VS.71).aspx) special to MSVC which seems to fulfill a similar task than the above.