# C++11 Call constructor of type after std::is_same to confirm its type

Tags: c++, c++11

The code below doesn't compile, it complains about "can't convert string to int" when I call func with type Foo and "can't convert int to string" when I call func with type Bar. I thought I already used std::is_same to tell if the type is a Foo or Bar, why this seems to be not working? What would be a better way to do this?

```
class Foo {
  Foo(int foo){}
};

class Bar {
  Bar(string foo){}
};

template<typename T>
void func(){
  if(std::is_same<T, Foo>::value) {
    T t(1);
  } else {
    T t("aaa");
  }
}

func<Foo>();
func<Bar>();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no *static* `if` in C++, so the code has to be compilable even if the branch is not taken.

You may solve that with specialization:

```
template<typename T>
void func(){
    T t("aaa");
}

template<>
void func<Foo>(){
    Foo t(1);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e3dee2ffb19007c)

Comment: What is `no static if`? If he change the code to: `int isSame = std::is_same<T, Foo>::value;` and then use `if(isSame)`, the code will work?

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh: That means `if` is a construct which is executed at runtime, not a compile-time. So no matter what `std::is_same<T, Foo>::value` returns, both branches should be compilable.

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh "no static if" means that the compiler won't evaluate the condition in the `if` and thus will not know which branch should be taken, so all branches of the `if` have to be evaluated by the compiler. You can have "almost static if" by using [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) though.

Comment: Note that C++17 looks like it's going to get `if constexpr (cond)`, where the branch is chosen at compile time.

Comment: Oh no, don't tell people to specialize function templates as a first attempt to solve a problem.  Template function specialization works differently than class template specialization and function overriding, and is very very rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a more general solution than the one proposed by Jarod42, you could use [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) (since c++11):

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<T, int>::value, void>::type func() {
    T t(1);
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<T, const char *>::value, void>::type func() {
    T t("abc");
}
```

This way, the compiler will only generate function where `enable_if` is true (this is a "almost static if").

You can use `std::enable_if` to check a lot of things, if you only need to check if the instantiation `T(1)` is valid you could use [SFINAE expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654067/what-is-expression-sfinae):

```
template<typename T>
decltype(T(1), void()) func(){
    T t(1);
}

template<typename T>
decltype(T(std::string()), void()) func() {
    T t("abc");
}
```

*See also [`std::is_constructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible).*

Comment: `template <typename T> decltype(T(1), void()) func() {}` would be more concise

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes, true. I wanted to post a general example but in this case this is much more concise. Answer updated.

Comment: Note also that for type which is constructible from both, you will have ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Tag dispatching is the way to go.

```
template<class T>
void func_impl( std::true_type T_is_Foo ) {
  T t(1);
}
template<class T>
void func_impl( std::false_type T_is_Foo ) {
  T t("aaa");
}
template<typename T>
void func(){
  return func_impl( std::is_same<T,Foo>{} );
}
```

You can mess around with template function specialization or SFINAE; both are fragile.  Template function specialization behaves unlike similar features elsewhere in C++, and SFINAE is impenetrable.

Another option in C++14 is to write a static if using lambdas.  This is impenetrable, but at least isolated from your actual code:

```
struct do_nothing{ template<class...Ts> void operator()(Ts&&...){} };

template<class F_true, class F_false=do_nothing>
auto static_if( std::true_type, F_true&& f_true, F_false&& f_false = do_nothing{} ) {
  return std::forward<F_true>(f_true);
}
template<class F_true, class F_false=do_nothing>
auto static_if( std::false_type, F_true&& f_true, F_false&& f_false = do_nothing{} ) {
  return std::forward<F_false>(f_false);
}

template<typename T>
void func(){
  static_if( std::is_same<T,Foo>{}, [&](auto&&){
    T t(1);
  }, [&](auto&&){
    T t("abc");
  })(1);
}
```

which at least looks like an `if` statement.  `static_if` returns the second or third argument depending on the static truth value of its first argument.

In this case, we pass in lambdas.  We then invoke the return value.

Only the lambda that matches the truth value of the first argument is invoked.

Comment: Wouldn't the lambda body have to be compiled anyway, even if you're not invoking it?

Comment: @barry right: code originally took an instance of a type we tested and passed it in as a `auto&&`.  Was lost in transcription.  Hack injected that will work with all current compilers, will dehack it.

Comment: Oh god. That's... truly impenetrable. Don't know whether to be horrified or impressed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SFINAE and create 2 overloaded functions for different T types

```
typename = std::enable_if<std::is_same<...>::value>::type
typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<...>::value> // for c++14


template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Foo, T>::value>::type
    func()
    {
        T t(4);
    }

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<Foo, T>::value>::type
    func()
    {
        T t("4");
    }
```