# Call function based on template argument type

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

There are two "C" functions:

```
void fooA(const char*);
void fooW(const wchar_t*);
```

Then there is a wrapper template function:

```
template<typename _TChar>
void foo(const _TChar* str)
{
     // call fooA or fooB based on actual type of _TChar
     // std::conditional .. ?
         // fooA(str); 
         // fooW(str);
}
```

If the caller calls `foo("Abc")`, this template function should make a compile-time call to `fooA`.  Similiarly, `foo(L"Abc")` should make the final call to `fooW`.

How do I do that? I thought of using `std::conditional` but couldn't make it.

I cannot make `fooA` or `fooB` overloaded, since these are C functions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can put **all** your `wchar_t` versions in a class template, say `overloads` and their `char` counter-parts in its specialization as shown below:

```
template<typename WideCharVersion> 
struct overloads
{
    void foo(wchar_t const * arg)
    {
       FooW(arg);
    }
    //more wchar_t functions
};

template<> 
struct overloads<std::false_type>
{
    void foo(char const * arg)
    {
       FooA(arg);
    }
    //more char functions
};

//a friendly alias!
template<typename T>
using is_wide_char = typename std::is_same<whar_t, T>::type;
```

And then you can use them as:

```
template<typename _TChar>
void foo(const _TChar* str)
{
    overloads<is_wide_char<_TChar>>::foo(str);
}
```

---

### Expression SFINAE makes it easy!

Other way is to use [Expression SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654067/what-is-expression-sfinae) which does not require to you write anything like `overloads` and does the same job with less code:

```
template<typename _TChar>
void foo(const _TChar* str)
{
    invokeOne(fooA, fooW, str);
}
```

And then you can implement `invokeOne` as:

```
 template<typename F1, typename F2, typename ... Args>
 auto invokeOne(F1 f1, F2 f2, Args && ... args) -> decltype(f1(args...))
 {
     return f1(args...);
 }

 template<typename F1, typename F2, typename ... Args>
 auto invokeOne(F1 f1, F2 f2, Args && ... args) -> decltype(f2(args...))
 {
     return f2(args...);
 }
```

Have a look at the [online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51ba9b0d4d69aff5).

In this approach, you don't have to add the overloads to the `overloads` class template **and** to its specialization. Instead you just pass them as arguments to `invokeOne` which calls the right overload for you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In what aspect is this better than the solution of lego and IanM_Matrix1?

Comment: @tamas.kenez: The first approach is similar. However, the SFINAE approach is different from their approach, which requires lesser code to get things done.

Answer (score 9):

Then overload another function. I'm assuming `foo` does more work and needs to be a template. Then call `foo_forward_call`, defined as such:

```
void foo_forward_call(char const* ptr) {
    FooA(ptr);
}

void foo_forward_call(wchar_t const* ptr) {
    FooW(ptr);
}
```

and at the call site:

```
template<typename _TChar>
void foo(const _TChar* str)
{
    foo_forward_call(str);
}
```

---

in C++1z you'll be able to use `constexpr if`, but to be honest, I think that overloaded solution is still more readable.

```
template<typename _TChar>
void foo(const _TChar* str)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same<_TChar, char>::value) {
        FooA(str);
    } else {
        FooW(str);
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `Boost.Hana`'s [`overload`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-functional.html#ga83e71bae315e299f9f5f9de77b012139):

```
template<typename _TChar>
void foo(const _TChar* str)
{
    hana::overload(fooA, fooW)(str);
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/qWSrHjpX7oh12bIC)

---

By the way: you should eschew using underscore-capital-letter names in your programs. They're reserved for implementation for any use (i.e. macros) and might lead to nasty name clashes.

Answer (score 6):

This seems like a really strange thing to do with templates. I would suggest using normal overloading instead:

```
void foo(const char* p) { fooA(p); }
void foo(const wchar_t* p) { fooW(p); }
```

If you insist on using template then you can do it like this:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T* p)
{
    // Declare functions here so that calling fooW with const char*
    // and 'calling' fooA with const wchar_t* would not cause compile error.
    void fooA(const T*);
    void fooW(const T*);

    if (std::is_same<char, T>::value)
        fooA(p);
    else
        fooW(p);
}
```

Comment: The linker will try to resolve *both* branches `if-else` and one of them will cause linker-error. If `T` is `char`, `fooW` will cause linker-error, else `fooA`.

Comment: True, but not always. This works with gcc and clang, not with vs. To fix this for vs, empty overloads should be defined, but then why bother with all this template stuff, just use plain overload.

Answer (score 5):

I like solving problems in general.  So let us design a mechanism to overload stuff.

`overload_t<...>` takes a set of callables in `...` and generates an object which uses standard overload resolution to choose between them, via inheritance of `operator()`:

```
template<class...Fs>
struct overload_t;
// the case where we have a function object:
template<class F>
struct overload_t<F>:F{
  overload_t(F f):F(std::move(f)){}
  using F::operator();
  // boilerplate to ensure these are enabled if possible:
  overload_t(overload_t&&)=default;
  overload_t(overload_t const&)=default;
  overload_t& operator=(overload_t&&)=default;
  overload_t& operator=(overload_t const&)=default;
};
// we cannot inherit from a function pointer.  So
// store one, and write an `operator()` that forwards to it:
template<class R, class...Args>
struct overload_t<R(*)(Args...)>{
  using F=R(*)(Args...);
  F f;
  overload_t(F fin):f(fin){}
  R operator()(Args...args)const{
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  overload_t(overload_t&&)=default;
  overload_t(overload_t const&)=default;
  overload_t& operator=(overload_t&&)=default;
  overload_t& operator=(overload_t const&)=default;
};
// the case where we have more than type to overload.
// recursively inherit from the one-arg and the rest-of-arg
// and using operator() to bring both of their () into equal standing:
template<class F0, class...Fs>
struct overload_t<F0,Fs...>:
  overload_t<F0>,
  overload_t<Fs...>
{
  using overload_t<F0>::operator();
  using overload_t<Fs...>::operator();
  overload_t(F0 f0, Fs...fs):
    overload_t<F0>(std::move(f0)),
    overload_t<Fs...>(std::move(fs)...)
  {}
  overload_t(overload_t&&)=default;
  overload_t(overload_t const&)=default;
  overload_t& operator=(overload_t&&)=default;
  overload_t& operator=(overload_t const&)=default;
};
// a helper function to create an overload set without
// having to specify types.  Will be obsolete in C++17:
template<class...Fs>
overload_t<Fs...> overload(Fs...fs){ return {std::move(fs)...};}
```

Now to generate a single object that is an overload of multiple, do this:

```
overload(FooA,FooW)( str );
```

And `str` will be dispatched to either based on the usual overload resolution rules.  This is useful elsewhere which is why it is worth writing, and the code at point of use is self documenting.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb3e138db9ca48d5) (wow, wrote it correct the first time!)

There are a number of improvements one can add to the above `overload_t`.

- Perfect forwarding of the `f`s during construction and in the helper function.
- Balanced Binary tree inheritance instead of linear (important of more than a few overloads are done).  This can have runtime and compiletime performance impliciations, especially for a large number of functions.
- Introspect incoming `Fs`; if they are `overload_t` balance the combined tree.
- In C++17, a `func<auto>` template that takes a function pointer and returns a function object that statelessly invokes it.  Compilers are relatively good at eliding function pointers, but they are better at it when there is no possible runtime state that could alter them.
- Deciding what to do for `overload_t<>`.  Currently it fails to compile; maybe it should just be an empty `struct {}`, or even a struct with an uncallable `operator()`.
- Examine existing libraries, like `boost::hana::overload` and see what differences there are.
- Expose the ability to extract which of the overloads would be called, maybe via a `static tag_t<F> which_overload_helper( Args... ) const` method and `template<class...Args> using which_overload = typename decltype( which_overload_helper( std::declval<Args>()... ) )::type;`
- Properly picking overloads when some of the incoming `Fs`s do/do not have a `const` `operator()`.  Should the function pointer have `const`, `volatile`, both or neither on `operator()`?  All 4?  How about `&&` vs `&` overloads?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe if there were more targetted functions or overloading wasn't the only problem you were trying to solve then it might be worthwhile using templates to get this done.

In this case though, simply write your overloads:

```
void foo(const char* x) { fooA(x); }
void foo(const wchar_t* x) { fooW(x); }
```

Comment: This is what I've done finally. But any change in one function requires change in another one also.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options.

1. Use an helper explicitly specialized `struct`:

   ```
   template <typename>
   struct helper;

   template<>
   struct helper<char>
   {
       void operator()(const char* x){ FooA(x); }
   };

   template<>
   struct helper<wchar_t>
   {
       void operator()(const wchar_t* x){ FooW(x); }
   };

   template <typename _TChar>
   void foo(const _TChar* str)
   {
       helper<_TChar>{}(str);
   }
   ```
2. Use a "static if" implementation (e.g. [boost::hana::eval_if](https://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Logical.html#gab64636f84de983575aac0208f5fa840c) or [my own](https://github.com/SuperV1234/vrm_core/blob/master/include/vrm/core/static_if/static_if.hpp)):

   ```
   template <typename _TChar>
   void foo(const _TChar* str)
   {
       vrm::core::static_if(std::is_same<_TChar, char>{})
           .then([](const auto* x_str){ FooA(x_str); })
           .else_([](const auto* x_str){ FooW(x_str); })(str);
   }
   ```
3. Use an helper overloaded function:

   ```
   void helper(const char* x) { FooA(x); }
   void helper(const wchar_t* x) { FooW(x); }

   template <typename _TChar>
   void foo(const _TChar* str)
   {
       helper(str);
   }
   ```

Comment: I think `.then(FooA).else_(FooW)` should work as well? If not, the designer of the library should make it work as well!

Comment: @Nawaz: it's more complicated - every branch requires needs to be a template that will only be instantiated if the condition matches. If it's not a template, compilation will fail. [I discussed this in my CppCon 2016 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXSsUqVSe2k).

Comment: I'm sure it is complicated. Still I feel that it can be made to work, by adding one more level of indirection.

Answer (score -1):

I think using `typeid()` is very elegant and readable, but not sure if there is any side effect.

```cpp
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
void foo(){
    if(typeid(T) == typeid(const char*)){
        fooA();
    }
    else if (typeid(T) == typeid(const wchar_t*)){
        fooB();
    }
}
```

Check it out in [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/j5TPGBdtFTtVA1Wa).

Comment: Thanks for adding the answer. But this doesn't really answer the question. It uses `typeid` which may require RTTI. Even if the type is determined at compile time, the `if-else` is not compile time expression.  templates are for compile time code, typeid goes towards runtime-type information and evaluation. See `if-constexpr` also.