# Template specialization for T and function-object that returns T

Tags: c++11, templates

Is there any way to template a function so that it can accept either a T in the generic case, or to a specialization if the template argument resolves to something that is callable, such as a functor, function pointer or `std::function`?
For example, I would want something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void use_this(T obj) {
  obj->do_stuff();
}

template<>
void use_this<???>(??? func) {
  use_this(func());
}

use_this(MyObj); // should call first one
use_this([MyObj](){ return MyObj; }); // should call the second one
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't partially specialize function templates, so you can't get the syntax which you indicate in your question.

You could write two function templates: one for when `T` is callable with no arguments, and one for when it isn't. You can then disable the function version using [expression SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654067/what-is-expression-sfinae#12654277) and add an extra function parameter to make overload resolution prefer that version when it's available:

```
template<typename T>
void use_this(T obj, float) {
  obj->do_stuff();
}

template<typename Func>
auto use_this (Func func, int) -> decltype(func(), void()) {
  use_this(func());
}
```

Then you can add a wrapper which supplies the disambiguating argument itself:

```
template <typename T>
void use_this(T&& t) {
    use_this(std::forward<T>(t), 0);   
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ad75f02a66698c1)

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply : std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, std::void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...> : std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z,void, Ts...>

template<class Sig>
using can_invoke = can_apply< std::result_of_t, Sig >;
```

We now have a traits class `can_invoke`.

You pass it a signature.  It is truthy if the signature is a valid call, and falsy otherwise.

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t< !can_invoke<T()> >
use_this( T obj ) {
  obj->do_stuff();
}
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t< can_invoke<T()> >
use_this( T func ) {
  use_this( func() );
}
```

I use some C++11, such as `enable_if_t`, `void_t` and `result_of_t`.  All are easy to write in C++11, and are easy to search for.

The behavior of `result_of` when passed an invalid signature was changed in C++14.  In C++11, it does not have to be SFINAE friendly.  We can replace `std::result_of_t` with `invoke_result_r` in C++11 as follows:

```
template<class Sig, class=void>
struct invoke_result {};
template<class Sig>
using invoke_result = typename invoke_result<Sig>::type;

template<class F, class...Args>
struct invoke_result<F(Args...),
  decltype( void( std::declval<F>()( std::declval<Args>()... ) ) )
> {
  using type = decltype( std::declval<F>()( std::declval<Args>()... ) );
};
```

This is now SFINAE friendly.

`can_apply` is similar to C++20's `is_detected`, but shorter and to the point.

Note that doing this in a non-C++11 compiler, like MSVC, is impractical.  You can do something similar with tag dispatching, however.