# How do I produce a compiler error upon an attempt to instantiate a template subclass method for certain non-type values?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, non-type

I would like to generate a compiler error if the using program calls a non-type template class method for a certain template argument.

```
typedef SubWithTemplate<1> SubWithTemplate1;
typedef SubWithTemplate<2> SubWithTemplate2;

SubWithTemplate1 &subWithTemplate1 = SubWithTemplate1::instance;
SubWithTemplate2 &subWithTemplate2 = SubWithTemplate2::instance;

subWithTemplate1.doSomething(); // Should compile OK
subWithTemplate1.doSomethingElse(); // Should compile OK
subWithTemplate2.doSomething(); // Should NOT compile OK
subWithTemplate2.doSomethingElse(); // Should compile OK
```

My starting point is the two following classes:

Super.h:

```
class Super {
    protected:
        Super() {}
    public:
        virtual void doSomething();
        void doSomethingElse();
};
```

Super.cpp:

```
void Super::doSomething() {}
void Super::doSomethingElse() {}
```

SubWithTemplate.h:

```
template<int SUBNUMBER>
class SubWithTemplate : public Super {

    public:
        static SubWithTemplate<SUBNUMBER> instance;
        void doSomething() {
            // Do something
        };

    private:
        SubWithTemplate() : Super() {}
};

template<int SUBNUMBER>
SubWithTemplate<SUBNUMBER> SubWithTemplate<SUBNUMBER>::instance;
```

I am not very fluent in Boost or mpl, but I have some vague feeling that BOOST_MPL_ASSERT could bring me some success. But I am not capable of understanding the nitty-gritty.

I tried something like:

SubWithTemplate.h:

```
...
void doSomething() {
    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG(<some test on SUBNUMBER being different from 2 and 7 and less than 25>, <what here?>, <what here?> )
};
...
```

I do not want the Super to be templatized, as it should be the same instantiation for all subclasses.

If I could avoid the use of virtual on doSomething, even better.

I would be very thankful if some more-than-me-expert could help me.

Comment: Assuming you can achieve this (which I doubt), but since `doSomething()` is virtual, how can you prevent it from being called via a pointer of type `Super*` to an object of type `SubWithTemplate<2>`? That call is only detectable at runtime!

Comment: I think that problem is solved by removing virtual and making the method protected. But still, a SubWithTemplate<2> instance may call its protected super method. In my case, that's acceptable because, the Super is not intended for inheritance by the library user, only the SubWithTemplate is exposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a great solution but... if you can use C++11, what about disabling `doSomething()` via SFINAE?

In the following example the `doSomething()` is enabled for all values of `SUBNUMBER` except 2

```
#include <type_traits>

class Super
 {
   protected:
      Super () {}
      void doSomething () {}

   public:
      void doSomethingElse () {}
 };

template <int SUBNUMBER>
class SubWithTemplate : public Super
 {
    public:
        static SubWithTemplate<SUBNUMBER> instance;

        template <int I = SUBNUMBER>
        typename std::enable_if<I!=2>::type doSomething ()
         { Super::doSomething(); }

    private:
        SubWithTemplate () : Super() {}
 };

template<int SUBNUMBER>
SubWithTemplate<SUBNUMBER> SubWithTemplate<SUBNUMBER>::instance;

typedef SubWithTemplate<1> SubWithTemplate1;
typedef SubWithTemplate<2> SubWithTemplate2;

int main()
 {
   SubWithTemplate1 &subWithTemplate1 = SubWithTemplate1::instance;
   SubWithTemplate2 &subWithTemplate2 = SubWithTemplate2::instance;

   subWithTemplate1.doSomething();     // OK
   subWithTemplate1.doSomethingElse(); // OK
   //subWithTemplate2.doSomething();   // compilation error
   subWithTemplate2.doSomethingElse(); // OK
 }
```

**--- EDIT ---**

As pointed by Guillaume Racicot (thanks!) this solution can be circumvented expliciting the template value (`I = SUBNUMBER` is only a default).

So if

```
subWithTemplate2.doSomething();
```

give a compilation error (as asked by the OP),

```
subWithTemplate2.doSomething<1>();
```

compile without problem.

To avoid this I can suggest a couple of solutions.

(1) you can add a `static_assert()`, in the body of the function, to impose that `I == SUBNUMBER`; something like

```
    template <int I = SUBNUMBER>
    typename std::enable_if<I!=2>::type doSomething ()
     {
       static_assert(I == SUBNUMBER, "I != SUBNUMBER; this in wrong");
       Super::doSomething();
     }
```

(2) as suggested by Guillaume Racicot (thanks again!), you can integrate `I == SUBNUMBER` in the `std::enable_if<>` test; something like

```
    template <int I = SUBNUMBER>
    typename std::enable_if<(I!=2) && (I == SUBNUMBER)>::type
       doSomething ()
     { Super::doSomething(); }
```

I find the second solution a little more elegant but I not an expert and, for me, it's a matter of taste.

**--- EDIT 2 ---**

> how could I prevent the SubWithTemplate class from being instantiated unless the SUBNUMBER is within a given interval?

Hot to prevent the full class? Not only the `doSomething()` method?

The first way that come in my mind is the use of a `static_alert()`.

By example, if you want permit only `SUBNUMBER`s in the range [5,10[ (5 included, 10 excluded), you can write the constructor as follows.

```
SubWithTemplate () : Super()
 { static_assert((SUBNUMBER >= 5) && (SUBNUMBER < 10), "error message"); }
```

But I suppose there are other ways.

**--- EDIT 3 ---**

Another way to prevent the SubWithTemplate class from being instantiated unless the SUBNUMBER is within a given interval.

A way that works in C++98 too.

It's based on default specialization and template default value.

```
class Super
 {
   protected:
      Super () {}
      void doSomething () {}

   public:
      void doSomethingElse () {}
 };

template<bool b> struct boolWrapper {};

template <int I, bool = (I >= 0) && (I <= 20)>
struct rangeLimit;

template <int I>
struct rangeLimit<I, true>
 { };

template <int SUBNUMBER>
class SubWithTemplate : public Super, public rangeLimit<SUBNUMBER>
 {
    public:
        static SubWithTemplate<SUBNUMBER> instance;

        void doSomething ()
         { Super::doSomething(); }

    private:
        SubWithTemplate () : Super() {}
 };

template<int SUBNUMBER>
SubWithTemplate<SUBNUMBER> SubWithTemplate<SUBNUMBER>::instance;

typedef SubWithTemplate<1> SubWithTemplate1;
typedef SubWithTemplate<2> SubWithTemplate2;
typedef SubWithTemplate<20> SubWithTemplate20;
//typedef SubWithTemplate<21> SubWithTemplate21; compilation error

int main()
 {
 }
```

Comment: Consider changing the condition in the enable_if to `I!=2 && I==SUBNUMBER` to protect the function from overriding the `I` value.

Comment: Thank to all of you for this solution. It works fine for me, my main requirements are satisfied. But if some of you find a more beautiful recipe, you are very welcome. @max66, you write "...Not a great solution...", what are you thinking of, more specificly?

Comment: @ØyvindRoth - Well... I think that it's not a great solution mainly because it's valid only from C++11 (your question isn't tagged C++11 but only C++, so I suppose that you asked for a C++98 solution) but also because working with SFINAE (although I love it) it's a little complex and it's really easy do the wrong thing (see, by example, the comment form Guillaume Racicot; answer updated accordingly)

Comment: I am using VS2013 which, as far as I understand, has an uncomplete C++11. It does not support SFINAE, but it supports the solution you suggested.

Comment: By the way, how could I prevent the SubWithTemplate class from being instantiated unless the SUBNUMBER is within a given interval?

Comment: @ØyvindRoth - SFINAE is a rule of C++ that precede C++11. My use of `std::enable_if` is a tipical SFINAE application (but a C++11 one). ps: answer improved (again) to try to respond to the last question. I have another idea but no time to verify it in this moment (maybe tomorrow).

Comment: Found out:
  static_assert(((SUBNUMBER >= 0) && (SUBNUMBER <= 20)),
   "class SubWithTemplate can only be instantiated with SUBNUMBER between 0 and 20"); on top in the SubWithTemplate declaration. Is that the preferred way?

Comment: @ØyvindRoth - answer improved (a new method to prevent the `SubWithTemplate` class from being instantiated unless the `SUBNUMBER` is within a given interval that works in C++98 too).

Comment: @ØyvindRoth VS2013 supports SFINAE, it just doesn't support [_expression_ SFINAE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12654277/5386374).  [This](http://ideone.com/TbhyQp) worked as far back as MSVC 2010, for example, thanks to its C++0x support including (most of) `<type_traits>`.  It wouldn't have been able to detect the existence of a specific member function, though, since that needs expression SFINAE (as far as I'm aware).