# assigning lambda to std::function

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, implicit-conversion, std-function

Why is the 2nd assignment allowed, when the inferred return type is std::nullptr_t? With function pointers this is forbidden.

And why doesn't the 2nd lambda run?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::function<void* ()> f;

    f = []() -> void* {
        printf ("runs\n");
        return nullptr;
    };
    f();

    f = []() {
        printf ("doesn't run\n");
        return nullptr; // -> std::nullptr_t
    };
    f();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well, nullptr is covariant with void*, so it should be ok.

Comment: What's "forbidden" about it? And where is the function pointer?

Comment: @Lightness: I think he means that you couldn't assign the second lambda to a `void* (pf)()`.

Comment: @Xeo: Okay I'm with you. He wasn't expecting the inferred return type to be compatible, which _would_ be true with a real function pointer.

Comment: **See also:** http://stackoverflow.com/q/5931214/560648

Answer (score 15):

`std::function` allows you to store anything, as long as the following holds for the signature you provided:

- all argument types are implicitly convertible to the argument types of the stored callable entity, and
- the return type of the stored callable entity is implicitly convertible to the return type of the signature

`std::nullptr_t` is implicitly convertible to any pointer type and yields the null pointer value of that pointer type.

Note that your code is not actually valid C++11, since you only have a `return expr;` and no trailing return type in the second lambda. As such no return type deduction will happen. GCC (and Clang, IIRC) implement this as an extension, since it's going to be part of the standard at some time.

Comment: And what about the second question, why isn't second lambda running? That indeed seems puzzling.

Comment: @icepack: It does, I'm currently investigating. MSVC yields the same behaviour.

Comment: 5.1.2(4) "If
a lambda-expression does not include a trailing-return-type, it is as if the trailing-return-type denotes the following type:
— if the compound-statement is of the form { attribute-specifier-seqoptreturn expression ; } ...snip...

— otherwise, *void*."

Comment: So, since the return type is void, the lambda is not compatible with the std::function, which thus considers itself empty.

Comment: @rici: If the `std::function` was empty, you'd get a `bad_function_call` exception. Also, you'd get an error before that if the return type deduced to `void` and you had a `return something;` in the body of the lambda. In OPs case, a GCC extension took care of that problem. Also, even if you specify the return type, the code is not run: http://liveworkspace.org/code/e4d8408d456c5227ce715a7740877fec.

Comment: replacing the `return nullptr;` with `return (void*)nullptr;` results in second lambda running

Comment: @icepack: Well, in that case the return type will be deduced as `void*` and the second lambda will be equivalent to the first, signature-wise. I'm still investigating, but it seems Clang runs both fine...

Comment: C++11 has return type deduction for lambdas, this is not an extension