# Pointer to function and std::function : the first one compiles and not the second one?

Tags: c++, c++11, functor, std-function

I'm not familiar with pointer to functions and I'm currently making some tests. But in the following program, I don't understand why the first version works and why the second version does not compile. What would be the correct syntax ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <functional>

template<typename Type> 
void display(const std::vector<Type>& v)
{
    if (!v.empty()) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size()-1; ++i)
            std::cout<<v[i]<<" ";
        std::cout<<v[v.size()-1];
    }
}

// Compiles 
template<typename Type> 
void apply1(std::vector<Type>& v, void(f)(Type*, Type*, Type))
{
    f(&*v.begin(), &*v.end(), 0);
}

// Does not compile
template<typename Type> 
void apply2(std::vector<Type>& v, std::function<void(Type*, Type*, Type)> f)
{
    f(&*v.begin(), &*v.end(), 0);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v = {1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.};
    display(v); std::cout<<std::endl;
    apply1(v, std::iota);
    display(v); std::cout<<std::endl;
    apply2(v, std::iota);
    display(v); std::cout<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is the following :

```
error: cannot resolve overloaded function 'iota' based on conversion to type 'std::function<void(double*, double*, double)>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function pointer provides what I call a *conversion context*. It explicitly states which of the overloads is meant, whilst `std::function` does not. The constructor of `std::function` takes in any callable entity and as such provides no context to disambiguate which overload is meant. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5931214/500104).

To manually disambiguate, either cast the function pointer

```
apply2(v, static_cast<void(*)(double*,double*,double)>(std::iota));
```

or use a named function pointer

```
void (*iota)(double*, double*, double) = std::iota;
apply2(v, iota);
```

or use a lambda

```
apply2(v, [](double* f, double* l, double d){ std::iota(f, l, d); });
```

Comment: So how can I modify `apply2` or its call to pass an algorithm like `std::iota` ?

Comment: Thanks. But I have another question : In the case where I call a function and not a function template : are the two implementations "equivalent" (apart from the fact that std::function is more "powerful") ?

Comment: @Vincent: Depends on what you define as *equivalent*, I guess. `std::function` can contain *any* callable entity, but also has indirection and possible allocation overhead.